# Translate, “The world with her” into Latin

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

English and Latin translation for a question that I can’t seem to answer definitively. I’m thinking I want this as a tattoo, to go along with a compass. My wife IS my whole world, but also we travel extensively and my my intent is to see the whole world, “with her.”

Comment: Meaning both with her I have the world, but also my intent is to see the world with her, in both cases my wife. We travel extensively.

Comment: What comes to my mind is something like /Cum illa orbem video/ (With her I see the world). Waiting for criticism and more idiomatic expression.

Comment: @ValentineVincent That works. You might want to consider *hac* (the woman here) or *ista* (the woman there by you) instead of *illa* (the woman over there, yonder, away from you and me). You also have alternatives to *orbem*, if you want them, although I think *orbem* works fine. I wonder, though, whether there might be a better word than *video*. I suspect there is...

Comment: You are all so very helpful! I love the different ways this can be expressed.

Answer (score 2):

*Orbis cum illa visendus*.

There are many ways to say this, and I've been running through many of them in my mind, but I haven't found any that are big improvements on this. There are many alternatives to *illa*, but I'm not convinced that any are improvements. Likewise for *orbis*.

Valentine Vincent suggested making *orbem* an object of *videre*, which could work, but I notice that the OP did not mention a verb in his English motto. I had thought that there might be a better alternative to *videre*, and while I was looking into *visere* as a possibility I stumbled across the adjective (gerundive) *visendus*, which is commonly applied to a sight worth seeing. I think that adding this gerundive gets Valantine Vincent's point across without adding a finite verb.

Obviously, there are other ways to say this, but this is one possibility.